# How to stop ontouch Action_Move and Action_touch event from going to the parent view in android

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I have a circle and triangle images inside a view pager.

I am trying to move the triangle image along the circle image using on-touch listener. 
But when i move the triangle, the screen/fragment also moves to the next as i am using a view pager.

What do i do so that when the on-touch listener of the triangle or circle is called then view pager on touch listener is not called.

**UPDATE: ADDING CODE**

```
mCurrTempIndicator.setOnTouchListener(new MyOnTouchListener());

private class MyOnTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

    private double startAngle;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                if (mThermostatCentreXOnScreen == 0 || mThermostatCentreYOnScreen == 0){

                    int centerXOnImage=mThermostatBgrd.getWidth()/2;
                    int centerYOnImage=mThermostatBgrd.getHeight()/2;

                    mThermostatCentreXOnScreen=mThermostatBgrd.getLeft()+centerXOnImage;
                    mThermostatCentreYOnScreen=mThermostatBgrd.getTop()+centerYOnImage;

                    mStartPosX = event.getRawX();
                    mStartPosY = event.getRawY();

                    float dx = event.getX() - mThermostatCentreXOnScreen;
                    float dy = event.getY() - mThermostatCentreYOnScreen;

                    float r = FloatMath.sqrt((dx * dx) + (dy * dy));

                    ////
                    break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                dx = event.getX() - mThermostatCentreXOnScreen;
                dy = event.getY() - mThermostatCentreYOnScreen;

                r = FloatMath.sqrt((dx * dx) + (dy * dy));

                mEndPosX = event.getX();
                mEndPosY = event.getY();

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                allowRotating = true;
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Thanks and regards, 
Sunny

Comment: And you are setting `MyOnTouchListener` to the circle and triangle?

Comment: i am setting it to the traingle

Comment: Could you post that code too?

Comment: its quite easy: the parent of your view (here ViewPager) is intercepting your touch events, you have to disable that behaviour

Answer (score 0):

If you `return true` in your `onTouchListener` for the triangle and circle it will consume the event and the parent won't receive it.

Comment: I was just typing this same answer and right before clicking submit yours came hahaha

Comment: but the point is that the screen starts moving while the code is in ACTION_MOVE case logic. it doesn't get to the return true statement

Comment: Did you try returning `true` in your `onTouchListener`?